# My Google Play Store is glitching so I can't download Minecraft

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-education-edition

About two days ago Minecraft Education Edition had an update, when I tried to update the game my Play Store just closed itself. So I uninstalled the game and tried to reinstall, when I did it went to 2 percent then said:

> Can't download Minecraft: Education Edition, try again, and if it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix this problem.

So I went into this and tried everything, resetting my device, clearing storage, clearing the cache of the Google Play Store and the download manager, and updating my device. But nothing works. Can someone help me?

**More Information**

- Google Chrome OS Version 96.0.4664.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- has 7.1 GB available
- needs 182 MB to reinstall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already had this kind of problem, and I had to clear the cache of Google play store.

https://www.gadgetsnow.com/how-to/unable-to-download-an-app-from-google-play-store-heres-how-to-fix-it/articleshow/69002909.cms

The TLDR: Go into the Google App Store App settings (the app itself, not minecraft's) and Clear Cache and Data.

You will have to sign back into the gmail account related with your games.

If that doesn't work, I would say go get the APK on a site and install it manually. Its less secure but it will bypass any problems the App Store may be stuck with.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this can happen if your device isn't compatible with the game. Check to see if your device is up to date. If it is, this could be a bug that is an issue you might want to take up with google playstores.

Comment: the issuse is that my sister has the same kind of chromebook and the game updated fine

Comment: @Pink_killer2 servers are messed up usually in google/amazon/microsoft. i would wait awhile, then do a full reset on your device, if you want to. (back up your device before a full reset) and then try reinstalling.

Answer (score -1):

Try going to [play.google.com](https://play.google.com) and signing into the same Google account that the device is logged in to and trying to install to your device from there. This may fix the issue because it will just transfer the APK to the device, instead of swapping the APK. This has happened with an app of mine called Sky Walk 2, and it fixed that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).